# Local machine interprocess communication with multiple independent processes (1 server, n clients)

Tags: python, linux, pipe, ipc

I would like to have a server process (preferably Python) that accepts simple messages and multiple clients (again, preferably Python) that connect to the server and send messages to it. The server and clients will only ever be running on the same local machine and the OS is Linux based. The server will be automatically started by the OS and the clients started later independent of the server. I strongly want to avoid installing a whole separate messaging framework/server to do this. The messages will be simple strings such as "kick" or even just a single byte representing the message type. It also needs to know when a connection is made and lost.

From these requirements, I think named pipes would be a feasible solution, with a new instance of that pipe created for each client connection. However, when I search for examples, all of the ones I have come across deal with processes that are spawned from the same parent process and not independently started which means they can pass a parent reference to the child.

Windows seems to allow multiple instances of a named pipe (one for each client connection), but I'm unsure if this is possible on a Linux based OS?

Please could someone point me in the right direction, preferably with a basic example, even if it's just pseudo-code.

I've looked at the multiprocessing module in Python, but this seems to be oriented around the server and client sharing the same process or having one spawn the other.

**Edit**
May be important, the host device is not guaranteed to have networking capabilities (embedded device).

Answer (score 1):

I've used [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/) for this sort of thing before.  it's a relatively lightweight library that exposes this sort of functionality

otherwise, you could implement it yourself by `bind`ing a socket in the server process and having clients `connect` to it.  this works fine for unix domain sockets, just pass `AF_UNIX` when creating the socket, e.g:

```
import socket

with socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX) as s:
    s.bind('/tmp/srv')
    s.listen(1)

    (c, addr) = s.accept()
    with c:
        c.send(b"hello world")
```

for the server, and:

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_UNIX) as c:
    c.connect('/tmp/srv')
    print(c.recv(8192))
```

for the client.

writing a protocol around this is more involved, which is where things like zmq really help where you can easily push JSON messages around

Comment: Thanks. I'll have another look at that library. Do you know if the socket approach would work with machines not having any physical network adaptors?

Comment: yup, should be fine.  even `localhost` should work if you don't have a physical interface

Comment: more specifically, domain sockets should just depend on whether the kernel has networking support compiled in and `localhost` relies on a "loopback" device being configured.  common distributions ensures both happen by default

Comment: Your example might be the easiest solution as the messages I will be sending are extremely basic. I like the fact that it doesn't require a port number.

Comment: zeromq supports unix domain sockets as well as providing various other nice features…